# Prove $-\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}=H_1x^2+H_2x^4+H_3x^6+H_4x^8+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$H_n$ is nth the harmonic numbers

$x<1$

(1)
$$-\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}=H_1x^2+H_2x^4+H_3x^6+H_4x^8+\cdots$$

A different approach of representing $\ln(x)$

---

let expand out the series

$=x^2+\left(x^4+\frac{x^4}{2}\right)+\left(x^6+\frac{x^6}{2}+\frac{x^6}{3}\right)+\left(x^8+\frac{x^8}{2}+\frac{x^8}{3}+\frac{x^8}{4}\right)+\cdots$

Simplified and factorised

$=x^2\left(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots\right)\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{3}+\cdots\right)$

Not knowing what to do next. I don't think I am moving in the right direction. Please, I need help to prove (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that:
$$ -\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 1}H_n x^n \tag{1}$$
or that:
$$ -\log(1-x) = \color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n}} = (1-x)\sum_{n\geq 1}H_n x^n = \color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq 1}(H_n-H_{n-1})x^n} \tag{2} $$
that is trivial.